# How to separate out GUIDs so as to perform a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, guid

I have output in SSRS when there is a massive string of GUIDs that form the parameters:

> FinancialYear=47faabe1-f6aa-e411-941e-00155d010d10&
>   FinancialPeriod=4dfaabe1-f6aa-e411-941e-00155d010d10&
>   Branch=eefb631b-4e1b-e611-9436-00155d010d10&
>   Branch=369d0919-edaa-e411-941e-00155d010d10&
>   Branch=e9a7dc75-f9aa-e411-941e-00155d010d10&
>   Branch=cb3a3c67-f9aa-e411-941e-00155d010d10&
>   Department=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&
>   Department=adb0f49a-4f1b-e611-9436-00155d010d10&
>   Department=487c64ae-4f1b-e611-9436-00155d010d10&
>   Department=4c9b0919-edaa-e411-941e-00155d010d10

Does anyone know a way to separate these out so as to do a join and obtain their names?

Ideally the output would look something like:

```
FinancialYear 2016
FinancialPeriod 12
Branch London
Branch Main
Branch Manchester
Branch Leeds
Department Mortgages
Department Loans
Department Insurance
Department Life Assurance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the aid of a parser

```
Declare @String varchar(max) = 'FinancialYear=47faabe1-f6aa-e411-941e-00155d010d10&FinancialPeriod=4dfaabe1-f6aa-e411-941e-00155d010d10&Branch=eefb631b-4e1b-e611-9436-00155d010d10&Branch=369d0919-edaa-e411-941e-00155d010d10&Branch=e9a7dc75-f9aa-e411-941e-00155d010d10&Branch=cb3a3c67-f9aa-e411-941e-00155d010d10&Department=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&Department=adb0f49a-4f1b-e611-9436-00155d010d10&Department=487c64ae-4f1b-e611-9436-00155d010d10&Department=4c9b0919-edaa-e411-941e-00155d010d10'
Select Seq   =Key_PS
      ,Item  =Substring(Key_Value,1,charindex('=',Key_Value)-1)
      ,Value =Substring(Key_Value,  charindex('=',Key_Value)+1,100)
 From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@String,'&')
```

Returns

```
Seq Item            Value
1   FinancialYear   47faabe1-f6aa-e411-941e-00155d010d10
2   FinancialPeriod 4dfaabe1-f6aa-e411-941e-00155d010d10
3   Branch          eefb631b-4e1b-e611-9436-00155d010d10
4   Branch          369d0919-edaa-e411-941e-00155d010d10
5   Branch          e9a7dc75-f9aa-e411-941e-00155d010d10
6   Branch          cb3a3c67-f9aa-e411-941e-00155d010d10
7   Department      00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
8   Department      adb0f49a-4f1b-e611-9436-00155d010d10
9   Department      487c64ae-4f1b-e611-9436-00155d010d10
10  Department      4c9b0919-edaa-e411-941e-00155d010d10
```

The UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')

Returns @ReturnTable Table (Key_PS int IDENTITY(1,1), Key_Value varchar(max))
As
Begin
   Declare @XML xml;Set @XML = Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delimeter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML)
   Insert Into @ReturnTable Select ltrim(rtrim(String.value('.', 'varchar(max)'))) FROM @XML.nodes('x') as T(String)
   Return 
End
```

---

> **EDIT - The following illustrates how to use Cross Apply if you need to generate a many-to-many**

```
Declare @executionLog table (ID int, parameters varchar(max))
Insert into @executionLog values
(1,'FinancialYear=47faabe1-f6aa-e411-941e-00155d010d10&FinancialPeriod=4dfaabe1-f6aa-e411-941e-00155d010d10&Branch=eefb631b-4e1b-e611-9436-00155d010d10&Branch=369d0919-edaa-e411-941e-00155d010d10&Branch=e9a7dc75-f9aa-e411-941e-00155d010d10&Branch=cb3a3c67-f9aa-e411-941e-00155d010d10&Department=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&Department=adb0f49a-4f1b-e611-9436-00155d010d10&Department=487c64ae-4f1b-e611-9436-00155d010d10&Department=4c9b0919-edaa-e411-941e-00155d010d10'),
(2,'FinancialYear=someGUID&FinancialPeriod=anotherGUID')

Select A.*
      ,B.*
 From  @executionLog A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Seq   =Key_PS
                      ,Item  =Substring(Key_Value,1,charindex('=',Key_Value)-1)
                      ,Value =Substring(Key_Value,  charindex('=',Key_Value)+1,100)
                 From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](parameters,'&')
             ) B
```

Comment: Thanks John that's much appreciated.

Comment: Hi John, I've just gone to use this within the report and it returns an error. I've used the parameters attribute instead of string text like so:  Declare @String varchar(max) = (SELECT e.parameters FROM executionLog e) 

Select Seq =Key_PS
      ,Item  =Substring(Key_Value,1,charindex('=',Key_Value)-1)
      ,Value =Substring(Key_Value,  charindex('=',Key_Value)+1,100)
   --INTO #Params
 From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@String,'&')

Comment: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

(0 row(s) affected)

Comment: @Bobnottm Apologies for the late response.   The udf returns a record set   , it appears that you are trying to push multiple records into one string variable. Perhaps you could expand your questions as to how you intend to use the parsed results. Be sure to ping me when you do

Comment: No worries, thanks for responding. I'm using the parameters column within the ReportServer/ExecutionLog. The reports we use allow for multiple parameters, hence the long strings of parameter details. I have a SSRS diagnostic report which shows when reports have failed or are slow, one of the cells is for parameters and essentially I'd like to see what parameters have been chosen that might have slowed the report down.

Comment: @Bobnottm Upon second look, your Select e.parameters has no where statement, so I presume is returning multiple records.  Let me know if this is desired, if so, a small tweak would be required via cross apply,

Comment: @Bobnottm updated my answer to illustrate a cross apply with the function

Comment: That would be fine except the source has to be Reportserver.[dbo].[ExecutionLog].Parameters rather than a string. If that's possible I could then create a temp table from the above and join on the names of the departments etc and have that as output.

Comment: @Bobnottm  the Declare (at)executionLog is just a demonstrative TABLE  not a string.  Replace (at)executionLog with   Reportserver.[dbo].[ExecutionLog]